# How does CASE WHEN THEN treat NULL values

Tags: sql, apache-spark

Assuming that I have the following piece of code in the SELECT clause which is being executed on Spark:

```
...
MEAN(CASE
         WHEN (col1 = 'A'
               AND (col3 = 'A' OR col4 = 'B')) THEN col2
     END) AS testing,
...
```

What would be the output of this query when `col2` is `NULL`? Are the rows containing `col2=NULL` be ignored by the `MEAN` function?

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: @TheWildHealer I am essentially executing SQL queries on Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer - don't know Apache Spark!

I've created a SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f7d5e/3.

If col2 is null, it is not included in the average, unless all the matching records are null.

Answer (score 1):

The result will be `NULL`.  It will have the type of `col2` -- this might matter in some databases (or if you are saving the result to a table).

What is the `MEAN()` function?  To calculate the average, use `AVG()`.  This is the standard function for calculating averages in SQL.